# How to give read and edit, but not delete permissions to records users don`t own?

Tags: security

We give CRED permissions by Profile. On OWD we give Public Read/Write.

Comment: whats the issue you are facing? If you elaborate your question then probably you will get a good answer

Comment: It`s just a general question. I want to know how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't give modify all permission. It will work.

Because simple delete will only allow you to delete only those records which are owned by you.